# How to force a has_many association using a different column as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Stuck in a - at first sight - simple problem in RoR. I am sure that is easy, but none answer here in SO helped me too much.

I have two ActiveRecord models: `Foo` has many `Bars`:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bars
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

That works like a charm. But I would like to use another field of `Foo` as foreign_key. The default is `foo_id` I would like to use `custom_id` as my foreign key. So I tried this  (as many solutions over the web suggested):

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bars, :foreign_key => 'custom_id', :class_name => 'Bars'
end

class Bars < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, :class_name => 'Foo'
end
```

But that doesn't work. i.e. ActiveRecord keeps binding `Foo` to `Bars` using `foo_id`.

Note: Including a self.primary_key='custom_id' in Foo would partially work. but I don't think that is a good idea. I want to keep foo_id as the primary key

**UPDATE:**

Given the feedback -Thank you guys-, I uploaded that example here https://github.com/montenegrodr/temporary_repository_ror :

- [Bar model](https://github.com/montenegrodr/temporary_repository_ror/blob/master/app/models/bar.rb)
- [Foo model](https://github.com/montenegrodr/temporary_repository_ror/blob/master/app/models/foo.rb)
- ** [This test is expected to PASS but it FAILS.](https://github.com/montenegrodr/temporary_repository_ror/blob/master/test/models/bar_test.rb#L8)**

**UPDATE #2:**

The answers does not satisfy the question above. Why the test is failing, my assumption is that it shouldn't fail.

**UPDATE #3:**

There're a couple of new answers I still need to assess. Will do that within 24 hours. Thanks.

**UPDATE #4:**

Thank you guys for all the answers. But none of them satisfied the criteria. I need to have that test passing. If it is not possible, can someone explain why? Is it a rails constraint?

Comment: I added an answer that will make your test pass, can take a look at it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify a different primary key **for the relationship** if you wish to achieve what you are looking to do.

To clarify, this is not the same as changing the `primary_key` of the model. This way is only changing the primary key used by the relationship. Please see the bottom of this post for examples.

I changed the keys from both using `custom_id` and changed one to `foo_id`. This way you have a better idea of what is going on between the models. You can use both `custom_id` if you wish, but I would suggest keeping the rails norm of `foo_id` for the belongs_to association.

If you want to use both of custom_id you'll have to add some specific `foreign_keys`

---

### Here are the models:

**Foo**

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars,
           primary_key: :custom_id, 
           foreign_key: :foo_id
end
```

**Bar**

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, 
             primary_key: :custom_id
end
```

---

### The Migrations

**CreateFoos**

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|

      t.integer :custom_id, index: {unique: true}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**CreateBars**

```
class CreateBars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :bars do |t|

      t.integer :foo_id, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

Here is the updated Test that should now be passing:

**Test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class BarTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    foo = Foo.new(id: 1, custom_id: 100)
    bar = Bar.new(foo: foo)

    assert bar.foo_id == foo.custom_id
    # bar.foo_id    = 100
    # foo.custom_id = 100
  end
end
```

---

**Examples**

```
Foo.find(1) #<Foo id: 1, custom_id: 100>
Bar.first #<Bar id: 1, foo_id: 100>

Bar.first.foo = #<Foo id: 1, custom_id: 100>
Bar.first.foo == Foo.find(1) # true
```

As you can see, this method does not change the primary key of `Foo` itself. It changes the primary key the relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` uses. Bar is realated to foo via `custom_id: 100`, but foo is still found with it's `id: 1` key, not its `custom_id` key.

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering it. I was looking for a solution that prevents me from changing the primary key..

Comment: This is not changing the Primary key of the model, It's only changing the primary key of the relationship. So the Primary key of `Foo` is still `id`, however the `Bar` to `Foo` relationship is using `Foo.custom_id` rather than `Foo.id`. This answer is not the same as what you did with `self.primary_key='custom_id'`. Please see the updated **Examples** section at the bottom of my answer for more info.

Answer (score 4):

While the above answer is correct I am adding some explanation to the answer.

For the `has_many` association to work properly you need to add `foreign_key: :custom_id` to **Foo** model. This will search bars table for records with `custom_id = id` of Foo

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars, foreign_key: :custom_id
end
```

Old Query

```
SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."foo_id" = $1  [["foo_id", 1]]
```

New Query

```
SELECT "bars".* FROM "bars" WHERE "bars"."custom_id" = $1  [["custom_id", 1]]
```

For the `belongs_to` association to work properly you need to add `foreign_key: :custom_id` to **Bar** model as well. This will search the `foos` table and return the record with `id = custom_id` of Foo instead of `foo_id`

```
class Bars < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: :custom_id
end
```

Old Query

```
# <Bar id: 1, foo_id: 1, custom_id: 2, ...>

SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 [["id", 1]]
```

New Query

```
SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."id" = $1 [["id", 2]]
```

Comment: Great explanation!, may i ask why does it need to emphasis the class_name as well with association.?

Comment: Thank you. I patched the POST, could you have a second look?

Answer (score 3):

I will leave you a complete file you can save and run with `ruby filename.rb` that will show the test pass. (The template for this test was taken from the Rails [bug_report_templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_gem.rb))

#### association_test.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

  # Activate the gem you are reporting the issue against.
  gem "activerecord", "5.2.0"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :foos, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :custom_id, index: { unique: true }
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :bars, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :custom_id, index: true
    t.timestamps
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, foreign_key: :custom_id, primary_key: :custom_id
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: :custom_id, primary_key: :custom_id
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_the_truth
    foo = Foo.new id: 1, custom_id: 100
    bar = Bar.new foo: foo
    assert foo.custom_id == bar.custom_id
  end
end
```

### Explanation

The class of both `Foo` and `Bar` can both be infered in the associations, so you dont have to specify `class_name` in either of them.

If you don't include the `primary_key` the relation will use the one it has by default: `id`. This is why your test `bar.foo_id == 1`, because `1` is the `id` of `Foo`, being that the default `primary_key`

> Remember the column `id` is created in each table by Rails unless you tell it explicitly not to.

Knowing hich column belongs to which table in the relation may be quite confusing, I will leave another example with different column names on each table for clarification. I also changed the model names to better understand which is playing each role.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :classrooms, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :my_classroom_id, index: { unique: true }
    t.timestamps
  end

  create_table :students, force: true do |t|
    t.integer :student_c_id, index: true
    t.timestamps
  end
end

class Classroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students, foreign_key: :student_c_id, primary_key: :my_classroom_id
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :classroom, foreign_key: :student_c_id, primary_key: :my_classroom_id
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_the_truth
    classroom = Classroom.new id: 1, my_classroom_id: 100
    student = Student.new classroom: classroom
    assert student.student_c_id == classroom.my_classroom_id
  end
end
```

Adding only the correct `primary_key` in both your models will make [your test](https://github.com/montenegrodr/temporary_repository_ror/blob/master/test/models/bar_test.rb#L8) pass.

Answer (score 2):

Set the [foreign_key](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key) and the [primary_key](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-primary-key) of Bar model to the desired column name (custom_id in this case).

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: "custom_id", primary_key: "custom_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1 => Given implementation needs `custom_id: integer` in `Bar`model

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bars, :class_name => "Bar", :foreign_key => "custom_id"
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, :class_name => "Foo", :foreign_key => "custom_id"
end
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that. But I'll give a second shot. Thanks.

Comment: @Montenegrodr Sure, let me know if you face any problem with this implementation.

Comment: Thank you. I patched the POST, could you have a second look?

Answer (score 1):

I cloned your repository and run the test code, it was fail

the other answers on your question are correct, but you wrote wrong test code and add unnecessary column on Foo model

actually you only need to add custom_id attribute to Bar model

```
class CreateBars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :bars do |t|

      t.integer :custom_id, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo, :class_name => "Foo", :foreign_key => "custom_id"
end
```

and for Foo model

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars, :class_name => "Bar", :foreign_key => "custom_id"
end
```

and then to test the relation

```
require 'test_helper'

class BarTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'the truth' do
    foo = Foo.new
    foo.save!
    bar = Bar.new(foo: foo)
    bar.save!

    assert foo.bar_ids.include?(bar.id)
    assert bar.foo_id == foo.id
  end
end
```

actually this is not how I wrote rails code
only for answering your question

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering it. The question is, how to design the models so this test `assert bar.foo_id == foo.custom_id` passes.

Comment: foo.custom_id means your Foo table's primary id is 'custom_id', not 'id'?